# Unique index for only one record with primary flag in one to many relation

Tags: mysql, indexing, constraints

I have table person and email in one to many relation.

```
PERSON 
|id|name|
| 1|Matt|

EMAIL
|id|person_id|  email|is_primary|
| 1|        1|a@a.com|      true|
| 2|        1|b@a.com|      true|
| 3|        1|c@a.com|     false|
```

Person can only have one email assigned as primary. How can i prevent situation like this using unique index or something else?

I have tried to work something around this. It seems that what I need here is something like WHERE statement if it only can be added to index.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX email_one_is_primary ON email(person_id,is_primary);
```

Comment: Not all problems can be solved in SQL.  Solve this one in your application code.

Answer (score 1):

Approaches:

1. Create a dummy column and insert value for dummy_col as 1 if it is primary else email_id;

   ALTER TABLE EMAIL
   ADD CONSTRAINT email_one_is_primary UNIQUE (person_id,dummy_col)

> ```
> EMAIL
> |id|person_id|  email|is_primary|dummy_col |
> | 1|        1|a@a.com|      true|1         |
> | 2|        1|b@a.com|      true|1         |
> | 3|        1|c@a.com|     false|c@a.com   |
> ```

2. make is_primary as varchar and store 1 for true and email_id for false

   ALTER TABLE EMAIL
   ADD CONSTRAINT email_one_is_primary UNIQUE (person_id,is_primary)

> ```
> EMAIL
> |id|person_id|  email|is_primary|
> | 1|        1|a@a.com|      1   |
> | 2|        1|b@a.com|      1   | 
> | 3|        1|c@a.com|   c@a.com|
> ```

Comment: This would allow only one email with is_primary = true and one with is_primary = false. What I need is one set as primary and many without that flag.

Comment: @SomalSomalski : I have updated the code. You may use  either of the mentioned approaches